# Proving the Urysohn's metrization theorem by using the Nagata-Smirnov's metrization theorem

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I need to prove the Urysohn's metrization theorem by using the Nagata-Smirnov's metrization theorem.

> **Urysohn's metrization theorem:**
>
> Every regular second-countable topological space is metrizable.
>
> **Nagata-Smirnov's metrization theorem:**
>
> Let $ (X,\tau ) $ be a topological space. Then, $ X $ is metrizable if and only if $ X $ is regular and has a countably locally finite base.
>
> Definition 1:
>
> A collection $ \mathcal{A} $ of subsets of a topological space $ (X,\tau) $ is said to be locally finite if each point of $ X $ has a neighborhood that intersects only finitely many elements of $ \mathcal{A} $.
>
> Definition 2:
>
> A collection $ \mathcal{B} $ of subsets of a topological space $ (X,\tau) $ is said to be countably locally finite(or $ \sigma $ - locally finite) if $ \mathcal{B} $ can be written as a countable union of collections $ \mathcal{B}_{n} $, each of which is locally finite.

**My Attempt:**

Let $ (X,\tau ) $ be a regular second-countable topological space. Then $ X $ has a countable base $ \mathcal{B}=\{B_{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} $. Put $ S_{n}=\lbrace B_{m}:m\in \{1,2,...,n\}\rbrace $ for each $ n\in \mathbb{N} $. Consider some particular $ n_{0}\in \mathbb{N} $. Let $ x\in X $. Observe that each neighborhood of $ x $ intersects only with finitely many elements of $ S_{n_{0}} $. Therefore for each $ n\in \mathbb{N} $, $ S_{n} $ is a locally finite collection. Hence $ \mathcal{B} $ is a countably locally finite base for $ X $. Then by the Nagata-Smirnov's metrization theorem $ (X,\tau ) $ is metrizable. Therefore every regular second-countable topological space is metrizable.

Is my proof correct? If not please help me correct it. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: It is correct! Only two remarks. First, _any finite collection is locally finite:_ anything intersects only finitely many members of $S_n$, even if it intersects all! In fact, you can simply take $S_n=\{B_n\}$. In other words: _any countable family is countably locally finite_.

Comment: @JesusRS Thanks a lot.